# Insert new row with id 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any possibility to delete the entire Data in table and insert new rows with id starts from 1

Delete Command helps to remove the data from table when we trying to insert new row that id will be Last inserted row id+1(if last inserted id is 5 then new id should be 6) but i want to store that id as 1

any suggestions other than truncate command, Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share what is wrong with `TRUNCATE`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After deleteing all records do

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

**Note**

**From MySQL Docs**  : [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that
>   have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal
>   to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value
>   is reset to the current maximum plus one. For InnoDB, if the value is
>   less than the current maximum value in the column, no error occurs and
>   the current sequence value is not changed.

Answer (score 2):

I presume from your description, that "id" is an identity column?

In that case,

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename;
```

with both delete all rows, and reset the identity field to populate from 1 again.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the downvote may be because the OP explicitly asked for a solution other than TRUNCATE.  Nevertheless, TRUNCATE is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you use the `TRUNCATE` command it will delete all the rows and reset the auto increment value:

```
TRUNCATE tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TRUNCATE TABLE [tableName]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

It will reset the auto increment value. From the docs linked above:

> If the table contains an identity column, the counter for that column is reset to the seed value defined for the column. If no seed was defined, the default value 1 is used. To retain the identity counter, use DELETE instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per requirement of OP, answer by @MudassirHasan is the best solution.

But there is another, but slightly lengthy way to do the same.

You can use `ALTER MODIFY` statement to remove `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute from `id`, and then again use `ALTER MODIFY` statement to re-add `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute to `id`. This is demonstrated below -

Here the example table `my_table` has following structure -

```
DESCRIBE my_table;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| col1  | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I populate the table with some random values as follows -

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1) VALUES
    -> ("abc"),
    -> ("def"),
    -> ("ghi");
```

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+
| id | col1 |
+----+------+
|  1 | abc  |
|  2 | def  |
|  3 | ghi  |
+----+------+
```

Now, I delete all records from `my_table` -

```
DELETE FROM my_table;
```

Now, I use `ALTER MODIFY` statement to remove `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute from column `id`

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
    -> MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Again, I use `ALTER MODIFY` statement to re-add `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute to column `id`

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    -> MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Now, I add a sample value `"abc"` to column `col1` -

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1) VALUES
    -> ("abc");
```

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+
| id | col1 |
+----+------+
|  1 | abc  |
+----+------+
```

The newly inserted row starts with `id` = `1`

Answer (score -1):

You will need to execute two commands in the following `sequence`:

First Delete all data from table

```
delete TABLE_NAME
```

Then set the ID to 1

```
insert into TABLE_NAME(ID) values(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

As @mhasan answers

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

is a way to do this.

Another approach is to drop id column and recreate it.

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` DROP `id`;
ALTER TABLE `tablename` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

But if your table has relations with other tables your will is not a good solution.